# Сборка только 1 таргета в CMake

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, сборка

Есть проект с различными таргетами в верхнем `CMakeLists.txt`. У этих таргетов свои зависимости. Могу ли я, не изменяя `CMakeLists.txt`, сбилдить только 1 таргет, имея только его зависимости в системе?

Проблема в том, что перед тем как делать `cmake --build . --target my_target` надо сгенерировать *build tree* с помощью `cmake ..`. И в момент этой генерации исполняются все команды верхнего `CMakeLists.txt`, в том числе поиск зависимостей для таргетов, которые не хочу билдить. А у меня в текущем контейнере установлены зависимости только для интересующего таргета, поэтому выдаёт ошибки. Можно ли как-то в момент `cmake ..` игнорировать части `CMakeLists.txt`, относящиеся не к моему таргету? Или это делается только редактированием `CMakeLists.txt` с кучей строк типа `IF (BUILD_THIS_TARGET)`?

Пример верхнего `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(lib_1_dep)
add_library(lib_1)
target_link_libraries(lib_1 PRIVATE lib_1_dep)

find_package(lib_2_dep)
add_library(lib_2)
target_link_libraries(lib_2 PRIVATE lib_2_dep)
```

Надо сбилдить только `lib_1`, `lib_2_dep` в системе не установлена.

Comment: Боюсь что нет. Этапы конфигурации и билда - разные и идут один за одним. Соответственно вы не можете узнать какой таргет будет билдится на этапе конфигурации. Вы, конечно, можете через свои переменные указать как конфигурировать проект